# OpenGL: How do I get the coordinates of a specific point after transformation?

Tags: opengl, cg

Suppose I have a point at (250,125,-20).
After the following transformation,

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(100.0, 50.0, 0.0);
glRotatef(-25.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
```

How can I get the value of current coordinates of that point?
Need I write a subroutine to multiply a matrix to a vector?
Are there any built-in solutions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't get the coordinates for a specific vertex (point) after a transformation, however for this particular case you can get the *ModelViewMatrix* after the translate/rotate is applied.

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(100.0, 50.0, 0.0);
glRotatef(-25.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);  

glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX , *your_matrix*);
//print your matrix to check if that is the desired transformation coordinates
```

There is no magic tape in OpenGL, you will have to write your own framework e.g: for every objects in your world a class where you hold the vertices and what data you find relevant.

Comment: Thank you! I've found a similar topic in [OpenGL FAQ](http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/transformations.htm#tran0120). It gives the same answer.