# OpenGLposition of point [0,0,0]

Tags: java, opengl, transformation

Is in opengl any function able tell me position of point[0,0,0] after using this code:

```
glPushMatrix();
glRotatef(1, 0, 1, 0);
```

compare to point[0,0,0] before transformation or do I just have to calculate it?

for example if I got transformation

```
glTranslatef(1, 0, 0);
```

I want to get[1,0,0]

Comment: You may want to consider using modern OpenGL and using an external matrix library. Here is a starting point: http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes , [You can get the coordinates for a specific vertex point after a transformation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5596318/1743852)

For Example:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(100.0, 50.0, 0.0);
glRotatef(-25.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);  

glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX , *your_matrix*);
//print your matrix to check if that is the desired transformation coordinates
```